# What are the differences using "any?" and "collect" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, logic

I have this method here:

```
def present? char_list
  !char_list.collect { |char| utf8?( char ) && char.blank? }.all?
end
```

I would like to replace it with this:

```
def present? char_list
  char_list.any? { |char| utf8?( char ) && !char.blank? }
end
```

I'm having trouble getting my head around whether or not they are logically equivalent. I feel like these methods are the same but I can't prove it. The goal of using `any?` is that it would stop processing as soon as it finds an element that meets the conditions.

Comment: Ruby does not have a method `String#blank`.

Comment: [`blank?`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#blank-questionmark-and-present-questionmark) is part of ActiveSupport.

Comment: It's not sufficient to ask if they're equivalent, you also need to know whether one is faster and/or more memory efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they're not equivalent, but you're close. To show you why, I'm going to take as axiomatic these two rules:

1. These two expressions are equivalent:

   ```
   a.collect {|x| pred(x) }.all?
   a.all? {|x| pred(x) }
   ```
2. These two expressions are equivalent:

   ```
   a.all? {|x| pred(x) }
   !a.any? {|x| !pred(x) }
   ```

Let's apply this to your code. First, pull the logic out of your block to make it a little easier to reason about:

```
def pred(char)
  utf8?(char) && char.blank?
end

!char_list.collect {|char| pred(char) }.all?
```

Now, applying axiom (1) we can change the `.collect {...}.all?` expression to `.all? {...}`, which gives us:

```
!char_list.all? {|char| pred(char) }
```

Applying axiom (2) we can turn the `all?` expression into a negated `any?`:

```
!!char_list.any? {|char| !pred(char) }
```

Of course, double negation (`!!`) is the same as no negation, so we have:

```
char_list.any? {|char| !pred(char) }
```

...and finally, we can put the logic back into the block:

```
char_list.any? {|char| !(utf8?(char) && char.blank?) }
```

As you can see you were almost there, but rather than just negating `char.blank?` you needed to negate the whole expression inside the block.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think what I was missing was the relationship between .all? and .any? and how to switch from one to the other.

Comment: To expand, I mean that I know that .all? and .any? are not opposites because [true].any? and [true].all? both are true. I think that is what was tripping me up.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is worth mentioning but `!(utf8?(char) && char.blank?)` could also be written as `!utf8?(char) || !char.blank?`.